# Drupal 6: PHP print based on two taxonomy terms

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, taxonomy

I am trying to use php to print something if the node has two specific terms.

Something like:

```
<?php
    $terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms($node, $key = 'tid');
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        if ($term->tid == 19) {
            print '19';
        }
        if ($term->tid == 21) {
            print '21';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Not sure if the Drupal code is correct, but your PHP syntax is not. The `if` arguments should be in parens and you should be doing a comparison check rather than assignment, so both your `if` statements should look like `if($tid == 19)`

Comment: I figured it out and changed the code accordingly.
Found out that I needed to add a foreach() command.

Answer (score 0):

[`taxonomy_node_get_terms()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_node_get_terms/6) returns an array with the term IDs as the array key. So to do something like the logic you're wanting, you'd need something like the following:

```
$tids = taxonomy_node_get_terms($node); 
// a $node object is passed as the only parameter in this case, so you would need to use node_load to get that
// the function has an optional second parameter, and 'tid' is the default, so it's not needed
$tids = array_keys($tids);
if (in_array(19, $tids)) {
  print '19';
}
if (in_array(21, $tids)) {
  print '21';
}
```